# How do I get my Tkinter Simpledialog on top?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have a Tk, and a Simpledialog, I copied my code, stripped it to get a minimal reproducible runnable code sample

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog

#page setup
page = Tk()
page.title("freechat")

#info popup
port = simpledialog.askinteger("Enter Port:", f"Please enter the port to the server", 
                                parent=page, minvalue=10000, maxvalue=60000,)

page.mainloop()
```

When you run this code though, you get this:
[image]

How can I get the popup in front, on top of the main window?

Things I tried:

- creating a TopLevel widget (but that creates a third, empty window which i don't need/want)
- creating it before/after the mainloop (not smart in hindsight)
- moving it up and down in the code between `page=Tk()` and `page.mailoop` (just guessing at this point)
- [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834017/tkinter-put-simpledialog-askinteger-in-a-toplevel-box) also sadly didn't help, I tried implementing its answers but the accepted one is basically identical to my code

So - what can I do (and is it smart to put the popup code in the main LOOP, won't it get opened multiple times? Didn't happen so far, but would it?)

Comment: Does the exact code from the accept answer also have this problem?

Comment: @MegaIng In theory the main window is to the bottom right of the popup, but if i remove the `root.geometry(...)`, then yes, the popup is behind the parent

Comment: @MegaIng did the accepted answer from the other question just get removed?

Comment: It just got unaccepted.

Comment: @MegaIng ah yes that's what i meant, did the acceptance get removed, bad wording on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you are supposed to use `askinteger`. If you use `askinteger` from a callback, e.g. during `mainloop` it is correctly on top:

```
page.after(50, lambda :simpledialog.askinteger("Enter Port:", f"Please enter the port to the server",
                                               parent=page, minvalue=10000, maxvalue=60000, ))
page.mainloop()
```

(Of course, you still need to correctly use the value.)

The core problem seems to be that `askinteger` is initializing the window of the parent, somehow messing with the order. Might be classified as a bug, you could try and raise a bug report.

Comment: so in the build i call a method, this method creates the askinteger, and handles the value?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. But filing a bug report is probably not a bad idea eitehr.

Comment: I never did this before, where should I do that?